# Convert a data frame column into a frequency distribution in R

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have recently started to work on some statistical problems in R and I have a query. I normally code in python and find the "collections.Counter" function quite useful. However I did not find any such equivalent command in R which was surprising since frequencies are used a lot in statistics.

for e.g. I have this table (data frame) -

```
df ->

c1          c2
reading1    2
reading2    3
reading3    1
reading4    3
reading5    2
reading6    4
reading7    1
reading8    2
reading9    4
reading10   5
```

and I want to get this in R-

```
value    frequency
    1    2
    2    3
    3    2
    4    2
    5    1
```

I hope this illustrates what I would like to do..
Any help is appreciated

and for illustration purposes - In python I could do this -

```
df_c2 = [2,3,1,3,2,4,1,2,4,5]
counter=collections.Counter(df$c2)
print (counter)

and get this - Counter({2: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1})
which I can manipulate using loops.
```

Comment: You could use the `table(df$c2)` function.

Comment: It helps to know how to look. The `table` function is the first hit for your "frequency" phrase in `help.search("frequency",package=c("base","stats"))`

Comment: I'm sympathetic to your problem: the `table(...)` function is one of the most poorly named in all of R, and it's a long list. If you're just learning R you might find the [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html) site useful.

Comment: apologies for late reply, I forgot about this question, then saw a "popular question badge" pop up!
I did use the table function at the end and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `table()`, which returns a named `vector()`:

```
> table(df$c2)

1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 2 2 1
```

You can return a `data.frame` like this:

```
> data.frame(table(df$c2))
  Var1 Freq
1    1    2
2    2    3
3    3    2
4    4    2
5    5    1
```

You can, of course, also use packages like the "tidyverse".

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  select(c2) %>% 
  group_by(c2) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n())
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#      c2  freq
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1     2
# 2     2     3
# 3     3     2
# 4     4     2
# 5     5     1
```

Comment: Very nice answer! I forgot that I asked this question!