# How to sort a dataframe column's frequency distribution

Tags: r

Closest question to mine: [Convert a data frame column into a frequency distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231246/convert-a-data-frame-column-into-a-frequency-distribution-in-r)

Other questions are mostly about plotting; not what I need

This post asks one more question than the one cited; namely, once the column in question is presented as a frequency distribution using "table", how can one sort that frequency distribution?

Simple example: define a dataframe:

```
a <- c(13, 14, 15, 16, 15, 15, 22, 21, 44, 21)
b <- c(16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 22, 17, 16, 16, 17)
test <- data.frame(a, b)

> test
    a  b
1  13 16
2  14 17
3  15 17
4  16 18
5  15 18
6  15 22
7  22 17
8  21 16
9  44 16
10 21 17
```

Find the frequency distribution of the second column of dataframe "test"

```
fd.test <- data.frame(table(test$b))

> fd.test
  Var1 Freq
1   16    3
2   17    4
3   18    2
4   22    1
```

Now attempt to sort on the column "Freq":

```
fd.test.sort <- fd.test[order(fd.test$Freq)]
```

The above returns "undefined columns selected"

What is particularly confusing is that as I am typing,"Freq" is suggested as a column name, which I then select.

I have also tried the following:

```
fd.test.sort <- fd.test[order(fd.test [, 2])]
```

But that returns the same error message

Using the example, what I am looking for is:

```
> fd.test.sort
  Var1 Freq
1   17    4
2   16    3
3   18    2
4   22    1
```

Comment: You need to add a comma after the `order()` function, like so: `fd.test[order(fd.test$Freq),]`. Add a minus sign (`-`) in front of the column name to sort in descending order (i.e. `order(-fd.test$Freq)`).

Comment: Respond as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`order`](https://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html) function in base R returns the ordered index values of the vector on which it was called, which in this case looks like this:

```
order(fd.test$Freq)
# [1] 4 3 1 2
```

These values can then be used to "index" a vector into a sorted vector:

```
fd.test$Var1[order(fd.test$Freq)]
# [1] 22 18 16 17
```

When using `order` to sort an object with multiple dimensions, however, its necessary to indicate which dimension should be sorted. If, as in this case, the goal is to sort a data.frame's rows (and to return all its columns), then a trailing comma is necessary. Further, to sort in descending order, use a minus sign (`-`) to reverse the output from `order`:

```
# equivalent to fd.test[c(2, 1, 3, 4),]
fd.test[order(-fd.test$Freq),]

#   Var1 Freq
# 2   17    4
# 1   16    3
# 3   18    2
# 4   22    1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this using `dplyr` is:

```
test %>% 
    count(b) %>%
    arrange(desc(n))
```

`desc()` is used to sort in descending order. Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      b     n
  <dbl> <int>
1    17     4
2    16     3
3    18     2
4    22     1
```

Comment: #Marius, does the use of "n" in your "arrange(desc(n))" define how the variable is to be used?  In other words, does dplyr require the user to supply the name of the <int> column?  If not, where is it otherwise defined?  To do ascending order, would it simply be "arrange(n)"?

Comment: `count()` creates a column named `n`, so you know what the name of the column is going to be. And yes, `arrange(n)` would give you a ascending order.